# what are the words used to describe pronunciations called?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

Following are some examples of words that describe the pronunciation of other words. What are these descriptive words called? I tried using search but it didn't help.

> hipster - hip.stuh
>
> say - sei
>
> career - kuh.reeuh
>
> pronunciation - pruh·nuhn·see·ei·shn

Comment: Transcriptions?

Comment: Are you talking about phonetic symbols?

Comment: You could probably call it **phonetic spelling**.

Comment: Pronunciation guide? I don't believe there is a specific word for it. Also worth noting that you'll often find that the guide uses a wider variety of symbols: [OED](https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-pronunciation/)

Comment: That is not phonetic spelling. My goodness. It's "sounds like" spelling. I don't think there is a word for it, specifically.

Comment: The querent has vamoosed, it would seem.

Answer (score 1):

It is known as *phonetic spelling.* Another way of telling a word's pronunciation is *phonetic pronunciation.*

Check this -

> Phonetic spelling is the representation of vocal sounds which express pronunciations of words. It is a system of spelling in which each letter represents invariably the same spoken sound. Some schools may use phonetic pronunciations to help children learn the spelling of difficult words, for instance, WEDNESDAY = Wed Nes Day.

[Reference is here.](https://www.dictionary.com/e/phonetic-spelling/)

Comment: phonetic spelling would have to use phonetic symbols. This does not.

Comment: @Lambie: No. What you're referring to is called *phonetic **transcription***, not ‘phonetic spelling’.

Comment: @Void phonetic spelling is a misnomer. For something to be phonetically written down or transcribed, you have to use the formal phonetic symbols for the phonemes. Assigning a sound to a letter is just "sounds-like spelling".

Answer (score 0):

Such words may appear in dictionaries or or glossaries.  You could call them the "pronunciation"

> When I make vocabulary cards, I always include both the spelling and the pronunciation on the card.

To be more technical, they are a type of phonetic transcription, that is they are a written representation of speech sounds.  There are a number of systems for phonetic transcription,  IPA is the best known one. You can also use an informal method of phonetic transcription, as in your examples.

> hipster /ˈhɪp.stə/ "hip.stuh"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formal text from IBM:

> Creating a pronunciation Words that the IBM Speech Recognition engine
> must recognize when users speak them, should be added to your
> grammars. The speech engine recognizes the pronunciations for
> thousands of words, and if you include those words in your grammars,
> the spoken words are recognized. [...]
>
> Choose a method to create or edit a pronunciation: Use a **sounds-like
> spelling** for the word.
> Use the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA)
> composer

So, I would use: sounds-like spelling

[pronunciation builder](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/wvs/6.1.1?topic=builder-creating-pronunciation)